# Get EntityReference from Organization-Service using oDATA REST and JavaScript

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm trying to get the information of the customer of a campaign response in Dynamics CRM 2016 (on-premise).
Because I'm on an entity form I want to use JavaScript for the REST queries.

Retrieving the information of the campaign response is not the problem.
In the response XML though, the PartyId is of type EntityReference

```
... <!-- more XML omitted -->
<d:PartyId m:type="Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Data.Services.EntityReference">
          <d:Id m:type="Edm.Guid">13cb3e39-46c5-e711-80ce-005056a04f81</d:Id>
          <d:LogicalName>contact</d:LogicalName>
          <d:Name>Jane Doe</d:Name>
          <d:RowVersion m:null="true" />
        </d:PartyId>
...<!-- more XML omitted -->
```

So now the problem is, I can't directly query dynamics for a contact using

```
https://example.com/OrganizationName/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/contactSet(guid'13cb3e39-46c5-e711-80ce-005056a04f81')
```

I get the following error

```
<error>
<code/>
<message xml:lang="de-DE">Resource not found for the segment 'contactSet'.</message>
</error>
```

because it's an EntityReference.

There does not seem to be an Endpoint like

`https://example.com/OrganizationName/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/EntityReferenceSet(guid'13cb3e39-46c5-e711-80ce-005056a04f81')`

I can't figure out how to retrieve the target of an entity reference using REST and Javascript. Is anybody out there who knows how to do it?

What I know from the C# framework is, that an EntityReference is only a Container that holds the real information about an referenced entity. So the ID that is given by

```
<d:PartyId m:type="Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Data.Services.EntityReference">
          <d:Id m:type="Edm.Guid">13cb3e39-46c5-e711-80ce-
```

is only the ID of the EntityReference and has to be resolved to the real ID of the contacts entity. But how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to query entities using OData endpoint:

```
https://example.com/OrganizationName/api/data/v8.0/contacts(13cb3e39-46c5-e711-80ce-005056a04f81)
```

or WCF\SOAP

```
https://example.com/OrganizationName/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/ContactSet(guid'13cb3e39-46c5-e711-80ce-005056a04f81')
```

Both links work properly on D365 v9 on-prem. But I don't have env to test directly on CRM 2016.

Comment: I now tried using the OData endpoint. The ID does not seem to be a contacts guid. I still need to get the EntityReference itself and then the information where it points to, I think. Of course, I could be wrong

Comment: From yours XML excerpt it's contact but you can also check activityparty entity for such id. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/entities/activityparty

Answer (score 1):

The OData url is case sensitive, so instead of `contactSet` use `ContactSet` to get result.

```
https://example.com/OrganizationName/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/ContactSet(guid'13cb3e39-46c5-e711-80ce-005056a04f81')
```

Comment: Hi Arun, thx for your comment. Unfortunately this does not seem to solve the problem. The error message still says  <error>
<code/>
<message xml:lang="de-DE">Resource not found for the segment 'ContactSet'.</message>
</error> I think I still need to get the information about the Party. Any Idea how to get that?

Comment: Trying to remember the 2011 endpoint, does the Guid need the curly braces?

Comment: Hi @Daryl, thx for the comment. I don't think it needs the braces. Other queries do succeed without the braces. So I think the query does not succeed, cause the given PartyId -> Id is the ID of an EntityReference, which has to be resolved. But I don't know how :(